# Sails.js MongoDB in bluemix not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js app using the sails.js framework and I'm trying to deploy this app on the bluemix cloud service.

I am trying a MongoDB instance in compose.io and I have a rather standard connection configuration in my local.js file:

```
connectMongo: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'sl-eu-lon-2-portal.1.dblayer.com',
port: 10438,
database: 'some-db'
}
```

It is not working. It's not deploying.
The error it gives is:

```
ERR error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
ERR error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.
```

This means, of course, that the database is 
But strangely it also gives this

```
ERR { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

Which doesn't make any sense, as I am not using port 27017, as noted above I am using 10438. 
The app is running locally, so I get that I am missing something on connecting to the database via the bluemix configurations, but I can't understand how come the 27017 pops up there.

Comment: You can also try asking this question directly to Compose.io Support. They offer email-based support to all users, and might be able to shed some light on the port issue. https://help.compose.com/docs/compose-email-support/

Comment: I have a feeling that this is not really a compose problem. I've been having the same problem even when I was using another source for MongoDB

Comment: Can you please add the code you are connecting to MongoDB? Please note that the problem is not only the port number, but you are trying to connect to a local MongoDB - 127.0.0.1, so your code is not reading the connectMongo information you provided.

Comment: I am defining the connection in the code above. I specifiy   connection:'connectMongo' in the models.js config file

Answer (score 0):

So your setup seems correct. Compare it with my setup:

**env/production.js**

```
connections: {
    prodMongoDb: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        host: process.env.MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR,
        port: 27017,
        database: 'my_database'
    }
},

models: {
    connection: 'prodMongoDb',
    migrate: 'safe' 
}
```

**env/development.js**

```
connections: {
    devMongoDb: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        database: 'my_database'
    }
},

models: {
    connection: 'devMongoDb',
    migrate: 'safe'
}
```

The fact that you are specifying a port 10438 but get an error regarding 27017 means that sails is not picking up your connection definition. How do you start your app?

Starting it like this:

```
npm start NODE_ENV="production"
```

will make sails pick up the production config.